# How to customize default Grails views - i.e. create.gsp

Tags: grails, view, default, gsp

I created a simple CRUD application, however one of my domain classes has over 80 attributes. The default input form is a total mess, hence I would like to organize it into groups of fields and place different groups of fields on different let's say jQuery tabs.

Could anyone tell me what's the best way to approach it? Best means minimal changes to the default.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the scaffolded views. You can change the templates used for the generation by running 'grails install-templates' or you can run 'grails generate-views' and customize the generated gsps to your liking.

Comment: "I would like to organize it into groups of fields" - off topic but this implies to me that you should consider splitting your big domain class in to several smaller ones (grouped as in the UI).

Comment: JanoB, I guess you're right - it will also make calling particular groups of fields easier. So what I need to do now is have a create.gsp that has several tabs, each tab with a different class create form and then one create button and one form validation for the whole. I would appreciate a little bit more detailed step by step guide on how to achieve this.

Comment: Well, if you split the domain class in to several, then "generate-all" will generate a create page for each.  You may then be able to tie it all together with something like webflows (at a guess): http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#webflow Consider that if the user has just entered 78 values and fails at the last hurdle, they're not going to be too impressed if they have to enter them all again.